# Why is this call to QFtp.put causing a crash?

Tags: c++, qt, ftp

I'm trying to upload a .avi file to an FTP server with QFtp:

```
void MyFTP::recordingDone(QString &fileName){
remainingFiles.push_back(new QString(fileName));

commands[qftp.connectToHost(globalProperties.ftpServer)] = "connect to host";
commands[qftp.login(globalProperties.ftpUsername,globalProperties.ftpPassword)] = "login";
commands[qftp.cd("myapp")] = "cd myapp";
commands[qftp.cd("Videos")] = "cd videos";    
QDir().cd(globalProperties.videoStorageLocation);
qDebug()<<"Opening "<<fileName<<endl;
if(QFile::exists(fileName)){
    qDebug()<<"File exists"<<endl;
}
else{
    qDebug()<<"File does not exist"<<endl;
}
QFile file(fileName);
qDebug()<<"putting"<<endl;
qftp.put(&file,fileName);
qDebug()<<"Closing ftp"<<endl;
qftp.close();
}
```

I'm connected to the command done signal and using the slot to debug output info:

```
void TrusionFTP::ftpCommandDone(int id, bool error){    
qDebug()<<"command: "<<commands[id]<<": "<<error;
if(error){
    qDebug()<<qftp.errorString()<<endl;
    if (qftp.hasPendingCommands()){
        qDebug()<<"Pending commands"<<endl;
    }
}
}
```

Here's the output before the crash:

```
Opening  "2012-Mar-06-12-19-57.avi" 

File exists 

putting 

Closing ftp 

command:  "connect to host" :  false 
command:  "login" :  false 
command:  "cd trusion" :  false 
command:  "cd videos" :  false
```

The crash also occurs if I don't close the ftp connection. The file never makes it onto the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
QFile file(fileName); 
ids.push_back(qftp.put(&file,fileName));
```

`file` resides on stack. The life time of `file` ends as soon as the member function `void MyFTP::recordingDone(QString &fileName)` returns. But the `qftp` has still reference to it. This is probably causing you the crash when you are trying to access `file` which no longer exists. Allocate `file` on heap instead.

Comment: This also applies to other language bindings for Qt, especially with garbage-collected languages, e.g. PyQt for Python. One needs to retain a reference to the `QFile` or any other `QIODevice` object being used.